# Swift NSUserDefaults setString:forKey:?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

NSUserDefaults has `integerForKey:`, `setInteger:forKey:` and `stringForKey:`, but does not have `setString:forKey:`.

How do you set a string to NSUserDefaults? It has `setObject:forKey:` but, in Swift, String is a struct. Is it ok to use `setObject:forKey:` to store a string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that [setObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set) can be used to apply a string is found in the discussion of the reference:

[image: discussion]

Since Swift String is bridged to NSString, the usage of setObject is valid. However as the other types mentioned are not accepted in NSUserDefaults using the setObject setter; they have their own convenience setters.

[image: convenience-inits]

Notwithstanding this, almost anything one can think of can be serialized and placed into NSUserDefaults using setObject with an NSData argument (as noted elsewhere on SO).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The other answers are exact and appreciated but I took this answer to accept because it mentions about Swift String structure bridged to NSString class. Also the usage of NSData is helpful.

Answer (score 22):

update: **Xcode 13.2.1 • Swift 5.5.2**

```
let string = "Hello World"

UserDefaults.standard.set(string, forKey: "string")

if let loadedString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "string") {
    print(loadedString) // "Hello World"
}
```

The nice thing about Swift is that it allows to you to easily extend the language. You can create your own `date(forKey:)` extending `UserDefaults` to create an instance method as follow:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func date(forKey defaultName:String) -> Date? {
        object(forKey: defaultName) as? Date
    }
}
```

---

```
let userName = "Chris Lattner"
let userAddress = "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, United States"
let userDOB = DateComponents(calendar: .init(identifier: .gregorian), year: 1978).date!

UserDefaults.standard.set(userName, forKey: "userName")
UserDefaults.standard.set(userAddress, forKey: "userAddress")
UserDefaults.standard.set(userDOB, forKey: "userDOB")

let loadedUserName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName")
let loadedUserAddress = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userAddress")
let loadedUserDOB = UserDefaults.standard.date(forKey: "userDOB")

print(loadedUserName ?? "nil")    // "Chris Lattner"
print(loadedUserAddress ?? "nil") // "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, United States"
print(loadedUserDOB?.description(with: .init(identifier: "en_US")) ?? "nil")  // "Sunday, January 1, 1978 at 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 19):

Swift 3 removed `.setObject`. Use `.set` instead. For example:

```
// Create UserDefaults
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

// Save String value to UserDefaults
// Using defaults.set(value: Any?, forKey: String)
defaults.set("Some string you want to save", forKey: "savedString")

// Get the String from UserDefaults
if let myString = defaults.string(forKey: "savedString") {
    print("defaults savedString: \(myString)")
}
```

Comment: Short and objective. Thanks!

Comment: What about retrieving the value with defaults.string(forKey: "savedString")? That seems to work.

Comment: @RanLearns great point. Not sure why I did it like that initially. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You can definitly use `setObject:forKey:`, the `NSDictionary` method  or even `setValue:forkey:` which is a `KVC` method.

It'll work just fine.