# Swift notification fire from datePicker

Tags: swift, datepicker, localnotification

i want set as local notification fireDate the date of my datePicker. I found that code from [another answer at S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27349421/2303865):

```
      @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
      @IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

var localNotification = UILocalNotification()   // You just need one
var notificationsCounter = 0

 // put your functions now
 func datePicker()            { myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time }
func notificationsOptions()  {
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
localNotification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
localNotification.alertBody = "Here is the seven o'clock notification"
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
//     you may add arbitrary key-value pairs to this dictionary.
//     However, the keys and values must be valid property-list types
//     if any are not, an exception is raised.
// localNotification.userInfo = [NSObject : AnyObject]?
}
  func toggleSwitch(){
if mySwitch.on{
    localNotification.fireDate = myDatePicker.date
} else {
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 999999999999)          // will never be fired
}
  }
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
datePicker()
notificationsOptions()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }
```

But it doesn't work, even if all seems correct...where is the problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet var notificationSwitch: UISwitch!

    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpNotificationsOptions()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func setUpNotificationsOptions()  {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .Time
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        localNotification.repeatInterval = .Day
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification.alertBody = "a notification"
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    }

    func toggleNotification() {
        if notificationSwitch.on {
            localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date.fireDate
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        } else {
            localNotification.fireDate = nil
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(localNotification)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func toggleSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
       toggleNotification()
    }
    @IBAction func dateChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
       toggleNotification()
    }
}
```

you will need those extensions:

```
extension NSDate {
    var minute: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Minute, fromDate: self)
    }
    var hour: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: self)
    }
    var day: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day, fromDate: self)
    }
    var month: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Month, fromDate: self)
    }
    var year: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Year, fromDate: self)
    }
    var fireDate: NSDate {
        let today = NSDate()
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1,
            year: today.year,
            month: today.month,
            day: { hour > today.hour || (hour  == today.hour
               &&  minute > today.minute) ? today.day : today.day+1 }(),
            hour: hour,
            minute: minute,
            second: 0,
            nanosecond: 0
            )!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man!!! "it just works"!!!!!! you are very great, you saved my day, i'm in your debt for this!

Comment: Now i have a problem: all that code is into a "Settings" controller...but i need  that localNotification.alertBody value is the content of an array that is in the main viewController. if i pass this value i get that error: use of unresolved identifier...how can i pass this limitation? It's possibile to declare a new indexPath in settings controller?

Comment: @Swift1 feel free to open another question and post the relative code and explanation there and if you would like me to take a look you can post the link here.

Comment: Ok i opened a new question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257339/swift-save-an-array-of-strings-to-nsuserdefaults-and-reuse-for-notification-aler   please help me! thank you

Comment: You know how to store datePicker value to NSuserdefaults?

Comment: Hey, i want that if i change date in picker view when i relaunch app date is the same of my last selection...can you help me? i was confused with http://stackoverflow.com/a/29126854/2303865 example

Comment: @Swift1 the comments area it is for comments, not questions. Open a new question asking how to make a datePicker value persist through launches and let me know when you are finished posting it.

Comment: Here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277619/swift-save-last-datepicker-selection

Comment: @Swift1 inside the method dateChanged add  NSUserDefaults().setDate(sender.date, forKey: "datePicker")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `fireDate` property is only being set inside the `toggleSwitch()` method. How is that method being reached? I would suggest you  move the content of that method right into your `notificationsOptions()` method.

As an aside, you might want to consider slightly more useful names for your methods: `datePicker()` and `notificationOptions()` are likely to cause you maintenance headaches later on because they aren't very descriptive.