# Save time (NSDate) in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, time, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save the time once the "user" reachs the Limit. So the limit is 10 for example and once he reachs this limit, i want to save the current time. Then he has to wait 1 hour to continue playing. I started doing this, but I already get an error, when I try this:

```
var CurrentTime = NSDate()
CurrentTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'NSUserDefaults' to type 'NSDate'

It seems like swift cannot save a 'NSDate' as a 'NSUserDefault'.

Comment: I think the error says quite the opposite: that you cannot save `NSUserDefault` as `NSDate`.

Comment: The linked question it is about string but it shows how to make a date persist using NSUserDefaults

Comment: Yeah could be right, but I need some help on how to solve this :)

Comment: @LeoDabus how can I access the the linked question. I just see a that you marked my question as a duplicate. (Sorry im new here)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126731/swift-nsuserdefaults-setstringforkey

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me when I have to use .setObject after standardUserDefaults() ?

Comment: When I save a String to NSUserDefault then I dont need .setObject for example

Comment: That was not a duplicate question. I reopened it. Your mistake is trying to assign an `NSUserDefaults` value to a variable of type `NSDate`.

Comment: Just use the `setObject:forKey:` method on `NSUserDefaults` to save the date.

Answer (score 5):

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() is a kind of dictionary, you dont use the dictionary as a date, you set a date value to one of its keys:

```
 let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()    

 // save to user defaults
 userDefaults.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "LimitReachedOnDate")

 // retrieve from user defaults
 let limitDate = userDefaults.objectForKey("LimitReachedOnDate") as? NSDate ?? NSDate.distantFuture()
```